# Laravel 5 не открывает папку Public на сервере

Tags: laravel

На локальной машине все работает отлично, а вот когда заливаю на сервер папки `Public` не видно в директорих(если удалить `.htaccess` внутри `Public` то папку становится видно) и при переходе по ссылке `site.ru/laravel/public` выдает ошибку `500 internal Server Error`. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: К логам apache2 у вас есть доступ?

Comment: @СтаниславГрот нет к ним доступа нету

Comment: @СтаниславГрот дали доступ мне, вот что в них `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/etoneraz/data/www/site.com/obmen/old/orders/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/etoneraz/data/www/site.com/obmen/old/orders/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107`права уже поставил на все папку 755, пробовал и 777 но ничего не меняется

Comment: Ошибка которая в логе, явно же говорит, что  нет прав на запись в лог ларавела. Нужно права на `storage` папку дать

Comment: Папки storage, bootstrap/cache и public/app, если я не ошибаюсь должны иметь необходимые права. Ставьте 777 - не ошибетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с той же проблемой, когда устанавливал Laravel на shared-хостинг. 500 ошибка, вероятнее всего, возникает из-за строчки `Options -MultiViews` в файле .htaccess, которую нужно закомментировать:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    #Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Я ее закоментил но теперь отображается просто пустая страничка

Comment: @rodgers, попробуйте обратиться по адресу `site.ru/laravel/public/index.php`

Comment: пробовал. тоже самое